# DataTables -- Titles Defined In Columns[] Not Generating Table Headers

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, datatables

I am working on a project with KnockoutJS where we are pulling data in via Ajax calls and storing them in ko.observableArray.  Currently, I have the following table in HTML:

```
`<table id="gpa">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: gpa">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: LEVEL"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: GPA_TYPE"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: HOURS_ATTEMPTED"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: HOURS_EARNED"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: GPA"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>`
```

The JavaScript we have for generating the content via DataTables and the associated options is:

```
var gpaTarget = {
    tableId: 'gpa',
    options: {
        paging: false,
        ordering: false,
        info: false,
        searching: false,
        processing: true,
        autoWidth: true
    },
    columns: [
        { title: 'Level', data: 'LEVEL' },
        { title: 'GPA Type', data: 'GPA_TYPE' },
        { title: 'Hours Attempted', data: 'HOURS_ATTEMPTED' },
        { title: 'Hours Earned', data: 'HOURS_EARNED' },
        { title: 'GPA', data: 'GPA' },
    ]
}

 //Add the DT target for Gpa data
    dataTableTargets.push(gpaTarget);



//Initialize datatables for the appropriate DOM elements
    if (dataTableTargets.length !== 0) {
        $(document).ready(function () {

            dataTableTargets.forEach(function (target) {
                var table = target.tableId;
                var options = target.options;
                $('#' + table).DataTable(options);
            });
```

Ideally, the idea from the DataTables.net site's description of how the Column.title feature works is that with a `<thead>` section, the title property for each column should render a simple column header (see https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.title for reference.)

However, I have no column headers unless I explicitly declare them in my HTML.  As their page says the `<thead>` element could be non-existent, or that the columns.title option can override the existing `<thead>` content, I am at a loss for why this is not working as expected.

Does anyone have any insight into what I might be doing incorrectly for this scenario?  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Datatables is a DOM-manipulating item. You need a binding handler to work with widgets that manipulate the DOM. You can start by looking here: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/24439/knockout-js-3-2-custom-binding-for-datatables-1-10x

Comment: @RoyJ Thanks, I am looking into this.  It is a bit of potential change to some pieces I have already completed, but may indeed be worth it, if it solves the problem.

The other option may be for some pages to not utilize knockout if all they are doing is rendering a static set of data that would rarely change.  However, those are the minority of the modules we are currently working on.

Thanks for giving me this lead, it is appreciated.

-Paul